# How to add padding for background image

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` which has a background image (a 9 patched png file).
How can I add padding to left and right so that the background image does not take up the whole width? I have tried `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight`, but that does not change anything.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
```

The whole background still stretches the whole screen width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't work because padding only acts on the contents of the `LinearLayout`. By using a second `LinearLayout` inside this one the padding will take effect. You must define the background color of the first `LinearLayout` that will be visible in the padding area.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="25dip"
    android:paddingRight="25dip"
    android:background="#FF000000">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: This is probably also possible by using an XML file for the background.

Comment: this is not so good as it increases the hierarchy depth. can you extend the answer with the details on how to implement this with XML?

Comment: i've posted another solution using inset drawable, so no need to extend. thank you.

Comment: You can improve this layout by changing the outer LinearLayout with a FrameLayout

Answer (score 123):

You should use xml drawable, specially designed for this purposes - **Inset Drawable**:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset

For example:

res/drawable/inset_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_background_image"
    android:insetRight="25dip"
    android:insetLeft="25dip" />
```

and then in your xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/inset_background">
```

Comment: This doesn't have the expected result for me, I have this same exact problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850400/inset-drawable-not-working-as-described-in-documentation

Answer (score 10):

Ur background drawable should be like this，using android:bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="48dp" android:drawable="@drawable/bg">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
android:background="@drawable/background">
```