# Inset drawable not working as described in documentation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

As described on Android Developer site:

> A drawable defined in XML that insets another drawable by a specified
>   distance. This is useful when a View needs a background that is
>   smaller than the View's actual bounds.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset

Instead of just moving the background and leaving the content in place in my case the inset is also moving the TextView.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_inset"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the bg_inset drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:insetLeft="100dp" />
```

And this is the result I get:
[image: Layout result]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, setting a background drawable also applies that drawable's padding to the view. Set the padding explicitly if you don't want it to match the background drawable.

Comment: Yeah it works, but for me it didn't suffice to set this in XML, I need to set it in code just after setting InserDrawable!

Comment: Yeah, the most recent call wins, so if you set the padding in the editor, and then set the background in code, the padding will come from the background.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `shape` with left-padding instead of `inset`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <padding android:left="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: if you want to use DP instead of PX, try my suggestion below. From my experience, InsetDrawable only works with pixels, which I find... unhelpful. To be honest, I am not happy with this solution, but hey, it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_placeholder"
        android:top="10dp" />
</layer-list>
```